# Is it possible for an Apple Watch app to require compass? (app for Apple Watch Series 5 only)

Tags: ios, apple-watch, compass, watchos

I'm building a watchOS companion app for a navigation app. It relies on the compass, which was introduced on Apple Watch Series 5. The app is useless without a compass.

I'm familiar with [`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uirequireddevicecapabilities), but that doesn't seem to offer the ability to require a compass.

**Is there a best practice for allowing a companion watchOS app to only be installed on Apple Watch devices with a compass?**

My alternative is to try to detect a heading and create a message in the app that says something like *Apple Watch with compass required* if it's not available. I wouldn't mention the Series 5 specifically for future-proofing against other future model names. This seems clunky, though, and it might be a better experience to prevent someone from even installing the app.

Comment: Can't you fallback to using GPS heading?  It won't be as accurate, so maybe you could show an alert to that effect.

Comment: Yes. As I said in the question I can do that within the app, but I’m wondering if there is a way to only allow the app to be installed on supported devices (devices with a compass) like with `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`.

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether a compass is available using [CLLocationManager.headingAvailable] and show an alert using WKAlertAction to tell the user.